# How to get resource files from the runnable jar file which are in buildpath

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, resources

I just need the files from jar file which are in resources directory at run time...

I know some ways just like...**but it only reads images**

```
ImageIO.read(Login.class.getResource("res/images/icon.png"));
```

Here I can read Images from the directory within JAR which is added to the build path in eclipse but here I am facing some issue while getting some ".so" file and some "cascade_hand.xml" file from resources/cascades/... , *I need them at run time to be available from the runnable .JAR file.*

I had tried this too..but this doesn't works..

```
CascadeClassifier cascade = new CascadeClassifier(
            "resources/cascades/haarcascade_mcs_leftear.xml");
```

nor this works...

```
CascadeClassifier cascade = new CascadeClassifier(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/cascades/haarcascade_mcs_leftear.xml");
```

I know there is way to copy that file in some temp directory and use them but I really don't know it how to do it ?

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/cascades/haarcascade_mcs_leftear.xml");
```

Is there any other way to access that type of files from Runnable JAR ?

I had also some issue in jar file created with eclipse.

Eclipse creates Runnable jar file and creates directories of resources directories within jar file which are in build path but, in real the all are created as one parent directory in jar file.

I have the folder hierarchy in eclipse is just like as following image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, OpenCV does the file reading in native code, so the only way is to first copy the data to a temporary file.

```
String tempDir="tmp"; //TODO: use a sensible default
Path tmp = Files.createTempFile(tempDir, "cv");
Files.copy(Login.class.getResourceAsStream(
    "resources/cascades/haarcascade_mcs_leftear.xml"), tmp);
CascadeClassifier cascade = new CascadeClassifier(tmp.toString());
```

Comment: Yep dear @llogiq I know it works but can't I access my original files which are already available in **JAR** ? because here I need to work within JAR file.....

Comment: Do you want to update the JAR? That may be possible using `Class.getResource(…)` and the JarFileSystem available since 1.7, but it would be very hacky.

Loading from within a jar with OpenCV is not directly possible. Depending on the operating system you run on, there may be options (e.g. under Linux and other unices, you could conceivably mount the jar via zipfs), but there's no portable solution.

Comment: +1 Finally I have to do this thing....Thanks for your support @llogiq :)   You too can up vote it and set as a favorite question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a classloader for reading the file

```
InputStream inn = ClassLoader
            .getSystemResourceAsStream("resources/cascades/haarcascade_mcs_leftear.xml");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nope I don't want any InputStream I need to access the file from the jar file because OpenCV reads file native code....

Comment: If OpenCV doesn't support reading via Classloader you could use an InputStream to read via classloader and write a temporary file to the filesystem and then use OpenCV to read that temporary file.

Comment: Nope bro I can not use InputStream because OpenCV requires the absolute path for the file. Yes I can use temp file mechanism but I am not aware of it